# Why number[i].grade is regarded as a pointer type cannot be compared with int type？

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 2
struct student
{
    int stu_NO;
    char name[20];
    int grade[i];
};
int main(void)
{
struct student number[N];
int i,grade_count=0;
int excellent_sum=0,good_sum=0,middle_sum=0,pass_sum=0,fail_sum=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    scanf("%d %c %d",&number[i].stu_NO,&number[i].name,&number[i].grade);
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(*number[i].grade>90)
       excellent_sum++;
    else if(*number[i].grade<=90||*number[i].grade>80)
           good_sum++;
    else if(*number[i].grade<=80||*number[i].grade>70)
           middle_sum++;
    else if(*number[i].grade<=70||*number[i].grade>=60)
           pass_sum++;
    else if(*number[i].grade<60)
          fail_sum++;
          grade_count+=*number[i].grade ;
}
printf("%d %d %d %d %d",excellent_sum,good_sum,middle_sum,pass_sum,fail_sum);
printf("%.2f %.3f %.4f %.5f %.6f",excellent_sum/N,good_sum/N,middle_sum/N,pass_sum/N,fail_sum/N);
printf("grade_count=%d",grade_count);
return 0;
}
```

I am not very clear what exactly the intrinsic link between pointers and arrays, this is my first structure code, I hope you can help me solve the problem.I will be here to grade[i] to grade, and the * removed, after changing code still exists some I have not thought of mistakes, grade_count has some strange errors. There is one final%d the last second printf. Can you help me to explain these small details based?

Comment: array indexing. maybe `number[i].grade[j]` will help you.

Comment: You've defined `grade` as an array. To access its contents you must index it, you can't just compare the whole array.

Comment: "this is my first structure code" - the compilation error has nothing to do with structures. You have `N` students and each student has `N` grades. Is that really the design that you had in mind? If yes, then it looks like you need a double `for` loop (one loop inside another), in order to handle every grade of every student.

Comment: `int grade[i];` should give you a compiler error, `i` is not defined at that point. This must be fixed before any sense can be made of the rest of the errors. Judging by the rest of your program I guess you just meant `int grade;` here

Comment: What you said is right, but now even if these modifications is the existence of some logic problems!

Answer (score 1):

As `int grade[N]` is an array, here by using `*number[i].grade` you are accessing the first element of `number[i].grade[N]`

That is `*number[i].grade` same as `number[i].grade[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int grade[N];
```

`grade` is an array. Thus, you can access it using `*number[i].grade` or `number[i].grade[0]` (which are equivalent).

`number[i].grade` is a pointer on `int`.

Comment: `number[i].grade` is not a pointer to `int`, it *decays* into a pointer to `int`. That's a big and important difference.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So, in the line

```
if (*number[i].grade > 90)
```

the expression `number[i].grade` has type "2-element array of `int`"; since the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it "decays" to type "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of `number[i].grade[0]`.

Thus, the expression `*number[i].grade` is equivalent to `number[i].grade[0]`.  The expression is parsed as `*(number[i].grade)`; the array subscript operator `[]` and component selection operator `.` have higher precedence than the unary `*` operator.